# Recursively inserting a model based on a XML source file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have a Category model that I want to seed the database with using an XML file as its source.

My xml looks like:

```
<categories>
  <category name="Bikes">
    <category name="Helmets"></category>
    <category name="Gloves"></category>
  </category>
</categories>
```

My Category model looks like:

```
Category
  parent_id
  name
```

How can I loop through the XML and insert new categories?  It has to be recursive in nature so I can also associate the correct parent_id for each category if it has one.

```
category = Category.new(
  parent_id: -1 
  name: "")
```

Comment: Are you looking for a ruby solution for this algorithmic problem, or are you asking how you'll fit this into a ruby-on-rails application?

Comment: @infiniteRefactor I thought about it and I am creating it as a rake task with a categories.xml file.   I need help with the ruby part (xml + recursion)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents. First you need to parse XML file. You can use REXML or any other XML parser for ruby.

```
require "rexml/document"
file = File.new( "mydoc.xml" )
doc = REXML::Document.new file
```

Then you can loop over top level categories first

```
doc.elements.each("categories/category") { |element| 
   addCategoryTree(element, nil)
}
```

`addCategoryTree` will be a recursive method that will create the top-level category and recursively call itself for each child.

```
def addCategoryTree(elementXml, parentObj)
  if parentObj.nil?
    categoryObj = createCategory(elementXml.attributes["name"], nil)
  else
    categoryObj = createCategory(elementXml.attributes["name"], parentObj)
  end
  elementXML.each("category") { |childXml|
    addCategoryTree(childXml, categoryObj)
  }
end
```

And in `createCategory` you can create the actual category object. First parameter to `createCategory` is the XML DOM object of the category and second parameter is the parent object you've created. I guess those are enough for creating the object.